# Building a block wall up a steep slope

Tags: walls, landscaping, concrete-block, slope

I would like to build a block wall up a steep slope, maybe 30%, and I don’t want to “stair step” the top, keeping it level, because it would render the wall nearly useless at the low points. If I have the top follow the slope how does one finish off the top? Without some type of finish detail the top would be a jagged mess.

Comment: The taller it is the harder it will be to retain structural integrity when it rains.  Soil is heavy, wet soil is heavier.  More details please...how long, how high

Comment: Sorry, its about 40 ft long and 6 ft high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A large masonry saw-blade and you cut the blocks at an angle to fill in the "stair-steps", then top with coping stones (or bricks) for a finish that isn't ugly. Or just mound up mortar on top for a less durable and uglier finish.